# When should one enable "Do not require Kerberos Preauthentication"?

Tags: active-directory

In active directory, there's an option `Do not require Kerberos Preauthentication`.

[image]

Does anyone know the use-case when it's checked?

Comment: If possible, never. It is a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

This check box would be required if the user must authenticate to an application that does not support Kerberos preauthentication.